# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 13, saw 4

Tags: pandas, numpy

i get this error "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 13, saw 4" running this code (python 3.8.6)

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


dfTextonly = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('internal_all_txt.csv', header=1, low_memory=False))
dfTextonly = dfTextonly[['Address','Status Code', 'Word Count' ,'Outlinks', 'Unique Outlinks', 'Inlinks', 'Unique Inlinks',"Canonical Link Element 1"]].copy()
dfJS = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('internal_all_js1.csv', header=1, low_memory=False))
dfJS = dfJS[['Address','Status Code', 'Word Count', 'Outlinks', 'Unique Outlinks', 'Inlinks', 'Unique Inlinks',"Canonical Link Element 1"]].copy()
df = pd.merge(dfTextonly, dfJS, left_on='Address', right_on='Address', how='outer')


df['Diff Wordcount'] = df['Word Count_y'] - df['Word Count_x']
df['Diff Outlinks'] = df['Outlinks_y'] - df['Outlinks_x']
df['Diff Unique Outlinks'] = df['Unique Outlinks_y'] - df['Unique Outlinks_x']
df['Diff Inlinks'] = df['Unique Inlinks_y'] - df['Unique Inlinks_x']
df["Canonicals are equal"] = np.where((df["Canonical Link Element 1_y"] == df["Canonical Link Element 1_x"]), "yes", "no")


df.to_excel("rendering-test.xlsx")
```

Any idea? Txh!

Comment: What does line 13 of your csv file look like?

Comment: answered in the comments

Answer (score 0):

What does line 13 of your csv file look like?

Im trying to merge 2 csvs. First one:

[https://como-bloquear.com/quienes-somos/,"Al](https://como-bloquear.com/quienes-somos/,%22Al) mando","QuiÃ©nes somos â€“ Acerca del proyecto Â«CÃ³mo BloquearÂ»","","200","QuiÃ©nes somos - Acerca del proyecto ""CÃ³mo Bloquear"" | CÃ³mo Bloquear","51","Indexable","text/html charset=UTF-8","OK","","67","642","0","0","","0","51","8","Acerca de lo que escribimos","27","max-snippet:-1, max-image-preview:large, max-video-preview:-1","","","https://como-bloquear.com/quienes-somos/","","","","","34715","355","6,517","1","","25","100,000","27","23","0","0","","","","","6df9bd469f22ce2a5eebf5dae862a2e0","0,705","","","","https://como-bloquear.com/quienes-somos/"

Second one:

[https://como-bloquear.com/politica-de-cookies/,"COOKIES](https://como-bloquear.com/politica-de-cookies/,%22COOKIES) DE GOOGLE ANALYTICS","PolÃ­tica de cookies","","200","PolÃ­tica de cookies | CÃ³mo Bloquear","52","Non-Indexable","text/html    charset=UTF-8","","noindex","35","320","0","0","","0","19","27","COOKIES DE GOOGLE ADSENSE","25","noindex,nofollow","","","","","","","","38293","540","9,158","1","","25","100,000","26","23","4","4","","","","","a061ce7c50acc78e96173dd72134fcb3","1,478","","","","https://como-bloquear.com/politica-de-cookies/"